# Boundary assignment in openFOAM

Tags: modeling, openfoam, openform, ansys

I created the mesh shown in the image below using snappyHexMesh.
I have assigned boundaries in blockMesh, but they have been removed after running snappy. My question is how to create boundaries like inlet/outlet to the mesh shown in the image. Thank you.

[image: 3D Mesh]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where exactly you would like to have the inlet/outlet boundaries? It seems that your backgroundmesh is significantly larger than the geometry and you have the ``locationInMesh`` at a point weird point. Furtheron, you haven't enabled the snapping step.

Comment: I assume that you don't want to get this thing done?

Answer (score 1):

you don't specify the boundary condition on the mesh. In meshing you only specify the name of the faces. For boundary conditions than go to folder 0 and you specify everything in there (U, p, T)